# DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync() doing nothing

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner

I've been using a camera `BarcodeScanner` (Microsoft's BarcodeScanner API) for 3 weeks now in my UWP application.
It's working well but sometimes, the preview window of the barcode is not opening and the `BarcodeScanner` is not turning on.

When I figured this out, I took my app in debug mode to see where was the problem and if they were some exceptions thrown.

Here's how I'm initializing the `BarcodeScanner` :

```cs
public async Task ClaimScannerAsync()
{
    string selector = Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeScanner.GetDeviceSelector();
    DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);

    if (_scanner == null)
        _scanner = await Windows.Devices.PointOfService.BarcodeScanner.FromIdAsync(deviceCollection[0].Id);

    if (_scanner != null)
    {
        if (_claimedBarcodeScanner == null)
            _claimedBarcodeScanner = await _scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();

        if (_claimedBarcodeScanner != null)
        {
            _claimedBarcodeScanner.DataReceived += ClaimedBarcodeScanner_DataReceivedAsync;
            _claimedBarcodeScanner.ReleaseDeviceRequested += ClaimedBarcodeScanner_ReleaseDeviceRequested;
            _claimedBarcodeScanner.IsDecodeDataEnabled = true;
            _claimedBarcodeScanner.IsDisabledOnDataReceived = true;
            await _claimedBarcodeScanner.EnableAsync();
            //await _claimedBarcodeScanner.ShowVideoPreviewAsync();
            await _claimedBarcodeScanner.StartSoftwareTriggerAsync();
            await StartPreviewAsync();

            Debug.WriteLine("Barcode Scanner claimed");
        }
    }
}
```

... and the problem seems to come from the line :

```cs
DeviceInformationCollection deviceCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
```

Called in :

```cs
internal async Task OnBarcodeExecuted(object dataContext)
{
    try
    {
        CurrentDataContext = dataContext;
        _scanner.Subscribe(OnBarcodeReceived);
        await _scanner.ClaimScannerAsync();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

}
```

`OnBarcodeReceived` in my ViewModel :

```cs
private void OnBarcodeReceived(string barcode)
{
    var ignored = Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        if(CurrentDataContext is IScannable)
        {
            IScannable item = (IScannable)CurrentDataContext;
            item.NumSerie = barcode;
        }
    });

}
```

where the code is just stopping and waiting without throwing an error.

So if someone could explain to me, why it's doing that and why the code doesn't throw any error after a certain amount of time ?

Comment: What barcode scanner API are you using? We need more information

Comment: I'm using the barcode api provided by microsoft, it's a camera barcode scanner 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/pos-barcodescanner

Comment: How are you calling `ClaimScannerAsync`?  Is it awaited, or in a try/catch?

Comment: Yes it's in a try/catch, but as I said it's not throwing any exception
I edited my post

Comment: Then what about the code that you are calling OnBarcodeExecuted? When you see no response from DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync, did you block your UI thread?

Comment: The fact that's not working isn't blocking my UI because it's async, so that issue is not critical but I want to know why it's doing that because I can't use the BarcodeScanner anymore when it's happening.

Edit : It's weird because today my barcode scanner works well again ...

Comment: Looks like the async operation itself has an operation which never returns. Can you see any difference while the barcode scnanner works well or not works? I will try consult someone else to see whether they can think about any possible reasons. But I think the best way is to troubleshoot this issue from your side first.

Comment: The only difference is that the code is not blocked when it's working so I don't really know what to do more..

Comment: @Reaperino I've consult from the internal channel and we think that: since this issue randomly happens. If you need to understand it better maybe you can create a support ticket https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support.  Some detailed logs may help us understand more about whether the issue is pending on DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync

Comment: Thanks for your interest, I'll do it as soon as I can.

Comment: I checked for the support, but it's like I need to subscribe to a support option for only $500

Comment: @Reaperino Hmm,yep. And if the problem is a Microsoft problem then the ticket should be free for you. Also please understand that we are not allowed to collect info from customer from a public forum.

Comment: @Reaperino I have the same problem here. The same project will run perfectly on my machine but on another machine the DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector)-Method won't return anything and my method call will never finish.

Did you already find a solution or a workaroud?